# Node js Express doesn't recognize npm inside projectfolder

Tags: node.js, express, dependencies, npm

I'm trying to install express through cmd in windows. My problem is installing dependencies after i've successfully installed express and built a skeleton of the framework. It requires to install dependencies. It even tells me the code line

> cd Myprojectname && npm install

But it says npm is not recognized as a command.
I don't know if the folder structure is the problem, but here it is:

```
 nodejs
       -Myprojectname\
                      -bin\
                      -public\
                      -routes\
                      -views\
                      -app.js
                      -package.json
       -node_modules\
       -node.exe
       -npm
       -npm.cmd
       -node_etw_provider.bat
       -node_etw_provider
       -package.json
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a fellow programmer i managed to track my own problem to a few words it's npm not a environment variable and so we just need to set it on cmd as so:

### C:\node> set path=%PATH%;%CD%

### C:\node> setx path "%PATH%"

Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/4276650/kulwant-singh

Answer (score 1):

i think your npm is not defined in evironment variables.

**To check** try running npm in any other folder or may be in another drive. Your npm was running before because npm executables was present in directory.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work in any other folder or directory how can i change this?

Comment: Thank you i did a bit of researcher about what you said and ended up on a website they gave me the solution to set npm to windows environment variable 
C:\node> set path=%PATH%;%CD%
C:\node> setx path "%PATH%"